# Safe way to write a text document using rest api

Tags: c#, .net, api, rest

Ok so I have a a text file that stores 20 or so JSON objects. I have the read and writing working when it locally hosted IIS express server. But when it is up on the hosting server it can only read form it. Now I can give the IIS user permissions to modify it and it works fine but not sure if that is a safe way of going about it. I'm using visual studio to edit it and publish it. Is their a way I can add the file so that by default the rest APIs can always write to the file and is safe?

Please comment if you need more information or code.

Using C# .net Example of what I'm using to write:

```
using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/linkObjs.txt"), true))
{
       outfile.Write(json + "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file is manipulated by whatever account the IIS Application pool is using, it MUST have access to the file (or directory if creating the file) or it can never work.

Comment: So giving access to just that file would be safe?

Comment: Generally speaking yes.